# How to generate training instances from multi-variate normal distribution?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I want to implement a perceptron for logistic regression in **Python**. For my training data, I want to generate 3000 training instances in two sets of random data points (1500 in each) from a multivariate normal distribution with

```
μ1 = [1, 0] 
μ2 = [0, 1.5]
Σ1 = [[1, 0.75]
     [0.75, 1] 
Σ2 = [[1, 0.75]
     [0.75, 1]]
```

and label them 0 and 1.
I want to generate testing data in the same way.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I have answered in case you need to refer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

mu1 = [1,0]
mu2 = [0,1.5]

sigma1 = [[1,0.75],[0.75,1]]
sigma2 = [[1,0.75],[0.75,1]]

set0 = np.append(np.random.multivariate_normal(mu1,sig1,1500),np.zeros((1500,1)),axis=1)
set1 = np.append(np.random.multivariate_normal(mu2,sig2,1500),np.ones((1500,1)),axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Really appreciate it.